# Facebook auth serverside calls back 2 times with the same code

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication, oauth-2.0

On our server-side authentication with Facebook we get a random and weird issue. Facebook calls the call back URL two times with the same code. This is only happening for some users and not on every login.
This is the flow we have implemented on our side: https://developers.facebook.com/…/manually-build-a-login-fl… . We have been using it since the beginning of 2013 and we haven't noticed any issues so far.

And this is the error we get when we are exchanging the code for an access token the second time.

{"error":{"message":"This authorization code has been used.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"traceID"}}
We tried to log this issue as a bug on https://developers.facebook.com/bugs but unfortunately it doesn't work.
It keeps showing unexpected error. Not to mention that i was unable to find the correct bug category.

Any idea on how we can fix this?
Thanks!

Comment: FYI: That is not a server-side callback, but simply a redirect that happens inside the browser.

Comment: of course, i was in a rush to write the question and mixed some stuff up :). Its still happening, 2 callbacks with the same code, any idea why?

Comment: That one request (the one your browser makes for the login dialog URL) gets answered with _two_ responses is technically rather impossible, from the HTTP point of view. I’d rather look for issues on your end, that could make the browser request the same URL a second time – script or img elements with an empty src attribute used to be the usual suspects to look for in cases

Comment: tried to find it, but nothing so far. still if i look over the requests on firebug, on each request i can see the Referer as facebook.com. if my site will do a new redirect, the referer will change, right?

Comment: I think it is not a new redirect (because who should have issued that, your site?), but rather simply a second request. / Do you have this only, so that I could have a look?

Comment: i have a picture with the network logs from firebug here

Comment: http://4.1m.yt/QZE57on.png

Comment: all the GET FbCallback have the referer facebook.com

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that users are clicking twice to process auth service? Try disabling the button before calling Facebook auth service

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using?

I just had this problem in Ruby using Devise for Rails. I had created an `omniauth.rb` initializer file, and added a config line item in the `devise.rb` initializer file.

If you did this too, you can remove the `omniauth.rb` initializer file and you should be good to go!

Comment: the code is written in c#, and i`m not using any kind of library, just normal web requests with callback